# How to Resize div by absolute div

Tags: html, css

Can #parent div resize by #child div  (*when #child div use position:absolute;)

just like #t_parent table is resize by #t_child table

```
<div id="parent" style="position:relative; width:500px; height:500px; border:#F00 3px solid;">
    <div id="child" style="position:absolute; left:20px; width:800px; height:500px; border:#06F 3px solid;"></div>
</div>



<table id="t_parent" width="500" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>

        <table id="t_child" width="800" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <td>TEXT</td>
          </tr>
        </table>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is fixed width/height - no, you cant resize.

Answer (score 0):

position absolute inside of position relative make the div detached from parent so you cant re-size.

But try remove `position:absolute` and give parent div `display:table` then you can re-size it.

Check this

http://jsfiddle.net/9gxyH/

Answer (score 0):

First thing if you want the child div resize its `parent div` so there no need for `position:absolute` because we use `position:absolute` when we want that the element not effect other elements.

but if you want this functionality so you need to do a little bit of js.

check http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/CLb5r/13/